# Improving .htaccess with SSL and WWW on Codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am trying to make SSL and Redirection work perfectly with my web application. I wish to achieve that always https://www.mydomain.com/ should be loaded in the browser - although, if he types a subdomain - it should be redirected to https://subdomain.mydomain.com/ instead.

I mean to say, everything should be SSL - here is what I am doing currently

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks    
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php        
    RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ index.php/$1

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

Also, I wish to improve this .htaccess file so to introduce more security measures plus also allow only js, css and images files to be accessible by everyone - rest everything hidden or redirected to a 404 page.

Please guide, I would be greatly thankful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These rewrite conditions may help you, I use this to make my CodeIgniter go to HTTPS:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```